# Make project in androd4.0 using Fragment in android?

Tags: android, fragment

I have attached the screenshots. Please check them. In the screenshots, I have used two screens, the first screen in left side and second in right side. When we click on the search button, then open other screen in right side but left side screen will not change. We use fragment functionality but I have not change the right side screen at run time. Please describe this problem so that we could make this application.

[image]

with example

[image]

Comment: what you are trying .. plz include your code...

Comment: Please share what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see http://developer.android.com/design for some ideas on how to make your UI work more naturally with the Android framework.  Next, load up the source code for [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html) and find the files that illustrate Fragments and the ActionBar.  Start with [FragmentLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentLayout.html): it's the simplest.